# python yaml update preserving order and comments

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

Im inserting a key into Yaml using python but I would like to preserve order and comments in the yaml

```
#This Key is used for identifying Parent tests
    ParentTest:
       test:
         JOb1: myjob
         name: testjob
         arrive: yes
```

Now Im using below code to insert new key

```
params['ParentTest']['test']['new_key']='new value'
yaml_output=yaml.dump(pipeline_params, default_flow_style=False)
```

How to preserve the exact order and comments ?

Below arrive moved up but I want to preserve order & comments as well

output is :

```
 ParentTest:
       test:
         arrive: yes
         JOb1: myjob
         name: testjob
```

Comment: Seems your YAML is not correctly formatted, you are missing spaces after `Job1:` and `name:`. Also `Parent != ParentTest`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pyyaml cannot keep comments, but [ruamel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) does.

Try this:

```
doc = ruamel.yaml.load(yaml, Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
doc['ParentTest']['test']['new_key'] = 'new value'
print ruamel.yaml.dump(doc, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

The order of keys will also be preserved.

Edit: Look at Anthon's answer from 2020: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59659659/93745

Comment: @shiv455 order will also be preserved

Comment: This preserves the order but not double quotes... I tried using yaml.preserve_quotes = True but no luck....

Answer (score 7):

Although @tinita's answer works, it uses the old ruamel.yaml API and
that gives you less control over the loading/dumping. Even so, you
cannot preserve the inconsistent indentation of your mappings: the key
`ParentTest` is indented four positions, the key `test` a further
three and the key `JOb1` only two positions. You can "only" set the
same indentation for all mappings (i.e their keys), and separate from
that the indentation of all sequences (i.e. their elements) and if
there is enough space, you can offset the sequence indicator (`-`) within 
the sequence element indent.

In the default, round-trip mode, ruamel.yaml preserves key order, and
additionally you can preserve quotes, folded and literal scalars.

With a slightly extended YAML input as example:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
#This Key is used for identifying Parent tests
    ParentTest:
       test:
         JOb1:
           - my
           - job
        #   ^ four indent positions for the sequence elements
        # ^   two position offset for the sequence indicator '-'
         name: 'testjob'  # quotes added to show working of .preserve_quotes = True
         arrive: yes
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
params = yaml.load(yaml_str)
params['ParentTest']['test']['new_key'] = 'new value'
params['ParentTest']['test'].yaml_add_eol_comment('some comment', key='new_key', column=40) # column is optional
yaml.dump(params, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
#This Key is used for identifying Parent tests
ParentTest:
    test:
        JOb1:
          - my
          - job
        #   ^ four indent positions for the sequence elements
        # ^   two position offset for the sequence indicator '-'
        name: 'testjob'   # quotes added to show working of .preserve_quotes = True
        arrive: yes
        new_key: new value              # some comment
```

Answer (score 1):

Addtion，if you want keep quote，you can try this:

```
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
```